# if statement always takes first condition python

Tags: python, excel, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am working on a basic python programme where I input a recipe I want to make and the quantity I want to make and the programme should calculate how much of each ingredient I need based on an excel file with the quantities per liter and subtracts the amounts I used from another excel file which contains a list of ingredients I have at home. this should be usable for multiple recipes and I tried this using a raw input and an if statement as can be seen below. However, the programme always uses the first recipe. Also when my input asks for the second recipe.

```
recipe = raw_input("give recipe ")
quantity = input("give quantity ")
print

if recipe == 'recipe1':
    wb1 = load_workbook('recipe1.xlsx')
elif recipe == 'recipe2':
    wb1 = load_workbook('recipe2.xlsx')
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

!! adittion: 
I mad this quick translation in English because I am writing my programme in Dutch and I forgot to implement something of which I now see that I causes my problem. 
    recipe = raw_input("give recipe ")
    quantity = input("give quantity ")
    print

```
if recipe == 'recipe1' or 'RECIPE1':
    wb1 = load_workbook('recipe1.xlsx')
elif recipe == 'recipe2' or 'RECIPE2':
    wb1 = load_workbook('recipe2.xlsx')
```

not that the difference is that I also check for writing in capitals only. This seems to cause my problem because when I leave it out it works fine.
Sorry for the mistake!

Comment: In my computer it's working as exected, can you also show what is the input you're using?

Comment: I've just run it, works fine

Comment: the input I am using is the

    'recipe = raw_input("give recipe ")'

or do you mean the excel files?

Comment: Not the line in your code but the text that you are typing when running your program.

Comment: the text I type is recipe1 if I want recipe 1 and recipe2 if I want recipe 2

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Python do you use?

Possibly, you would have to write `input()` instead of `raw_input()` (which would result in a non-string variable)? What is the `print` statement used for?

Comment: I use python 2.7.10.0. The print statement is just to create a blank in my outcome for overview

Comment: I also tried using input() but then when I type for example recipe1 it says that recipe1 is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake:
it should be

```
if recipe == 'recipe1' or recipe == 'RECIPE1':
    wb1 = load_workbook('recipe1.xlsx')
elif recipe == 'recipe2' or recipe == 'RECIPE2':
    wb1 = load_workbook('recipe2.xlsx')
```

thank you all for taking the time to help me!

Comment: You could also use `recipe.lower() == 'recipe1'`.